# It is possible to save NSTimer* in NSData?

Tags: nstimer, nsdata

I have the following scenario:
I need to save a lot of information for alarms in xcdatamodel.
Between that info, there is a NSTimer* that I need to use later to invalidate the timer, that I created before.

I tried:

```
NSTimer * timerOptions;
NSData *timerArray = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject: timerOptions];
[alarm setValue:timerArray forKey:@"timer"]; //(it crashes here with msg: [__NSCFTimer encodeWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x170368040)
```

in `alarm.h` I have

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *timer;
```

and in xcdatamodel, `timer` is of type Binary Data

then when read the value I called:

```
NSArray *tt = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:[alarm timer]];
NSTimer *t = [tt mutableCopy][0];
```

There is a way to save a variable of type `NSTimer*` somehow to be retrieved?

Thanks

Comment: NSTimer is not NSCoding compliant. You may have to save each parameter you want yourself by creating a new class/structure

Comment: But I need to save the NSTimer*, in order to be able to stop later the timer. how to stop a timer if I doi not have the NSTimer* to it?

Comment: @Mihaela where you able to find the solution for this ?